# Позиционирование блока в меню шапки

Tags: css

пытаюсь переместить второе меню в правую часть экрана, но не выходит. Я плохо разбираюсь в позиционирование элементов, не могли бы вы подсказать как исправить мою проблему и на каких источниках можно изучить позиционирование элементов.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}
  
nav {
  margin-top: -2%;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #3E4554;
  padding: 12px 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
}

.search input {
  margin-left: 128px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 42px;
}

.menu a {
  margin-right: 50px;
  color: #3E4554;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #6A7BFF;
}

.rightmenu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;

  
}

.rightmenu a {
  color: #3E4554;
  margin-right: 35px;
  
}

.rightmenu a:hover {
  color: #6A7BFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sport-defense - Main</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Спортивный проект для достижений">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="img/favicon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
     
<nav>   
    <div class="header">
        <div>
        <a class="logo"><img alt="Logo" src="#"/></a>
            <form class="search" action="site.html">
                <input name="s" placeholder="Поиск" type="search">
            </form>
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="#">Новости</a>
                <a href="#">Рейтинг</a>
                <a href="#">Соревнования</a>
                <a href="#">Событие</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightmenu">
        <a href="#">Подписка</a>
        <a href="#">Подписка</a>
        <a href="#">Подписка</a>
        <a href="#">Подписка</a>
        <a href="#">Подписка</a>
    </div>
</nav>     




  </header>

<main>
<aside class="secondary-nav" aria-label="Site bar">
   <h1>Ваши тренировки</h1>
    <section>
            <h2>Готовые программы для занятия</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Отжимания</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подтягивания</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Приседания</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Брусья</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section> 
            
 <section class="secondary-nav1" aria-label="Secondary">
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">To-Do list</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">План тренировок</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Питание</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Задачи</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Цели</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Своя тренировка</a></li>
        </ul>
</section>        
</aside>

 <form action="/site.html">          
    <img src="background.png" alt="Фон профиля">
        <input type="file">
 </form>

<form action="/site.html">
    <img src="avatar.jpg" alt="Аватар пользователя">
        <input type="file">
</form>

<div class="data">
    <p>Масиков Артем</p>
        <ul>
            <li>sport-defense/hydramist</li>
            <li>Написать</li>
            <li>Следовать</li>
        </ul>
</div>

<aside class="social" aria-label="Secondary">  
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside> 

<div>
    <a>Россия, Красноярск</a>
    <a>Регистрация, 1 месяц назад</a>
    <a>Full Stack Developer | Co-Founder & Front-End Developer of this very site.</a>
</div>
    
<div>
    <p>Ваши данные</p>
    <a href="#">Статистика</a>
    <a href="#">Достиженния</a>
    <a href="#">Ваши новости</a>
    <a href="#">Фотоальбом</a>
</div>
</main>

<footer>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Политика конфиденциальности</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пользовательское соглашение</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Правила сообщества</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Еще</a></li>
</ul>    

<script defer src="/js/load.js"></script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сделал таким методом, но верно ли? .rightmenu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 56px;

Comment: не правильно , есть проще методы